# Json array and retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit

I've this kind of json response:

```
 {
  error: false
  stats: {
          punti: 150
          punti2: 200
         }-
 }
```

I created a **StatsReceiver** class:

```
public class StatsReceiver {
 Boolean error;
 Stats stat;

 public Boolean isError() {
     if (error == null)
         return true;
     else
         return error;
 }

 public int getPunti() {
     if (stat == null)
         return -1;
     else
         return stat.getPunti();
 }

 private class Stats {
     private int punti = 0;

     public int getPunti() {
         return punti;
     }

    public void setPunti(int punti) {
         this.punti = punti;
     }

     public int getPunti2() {
         return punti2;
     }

     public void setPunti2(int punti2) {
         this.punti2 = punti2;
     }

     private int punti2 = 0;

     public Stats(int punti, int punti2) {
         this.punti = punti;
         this.punti2 = punti2;
     }
 }
}
```

Next:

```
 @GET("/v1/stats")
 void stats(@Header("Auth") String code,
              Callback<StatsReceiver> object);
```

Now when I do:

```
 apiServiceUsers.stats(apiKey, new Callback<StatsReceiver>() {
        @Override
        public void success(StatsReceiver statsReceiver, Response response) {
            if (statsReceiver.isError()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, statsReceiver.getPunti(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Error is **false** as expected, but **getPunti()** return always -1, so stat object is always **null**.

What's wrong?

P.S in the Log console, there is:

```
 {"error":false,"stats":{"punti":150,"punti2":200}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON example the key is `stats`; but in your Java class the member variable is called `stat`. For Gson to work, these must be either exactly the same, or you must use `@SerializedName` to tell Gson which JSON key corresponds to which variable:

```
@SerializedName("stats")
Stats statOrSomethingElseEntirely;
```